# how to made grid layout using cardView?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

This is Adapter for grid view. I included image and letters in adapter class.

```
public class GridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {              
    private int icons[];
    private String letters[];
    private Context context;
    private LayoutInflaterinflater;

    public GridAdapter(Context context , int icons[] , String letters[]){
        this.context=context;
        this.icons=icons;
        this.letters=letters;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return letters.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return letters[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View gridView = convertView;
        if(convertView == null){
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            gridView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_layout,null);
        }

        ImageView icon = (ImageView) gridView.findViewById(R.id.icons);
        TextView letter = (TextView) gridView.findViewById(R.id.letters);

        icon.setImageResource(icons[position]);

        letter.setText(letters[position]);

        return gridView;
    }
}
```

This is main class. I made 8 card and want to add an activity for each card.how to add activity for each card.

```
public class NavigationMainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    GridView gridView;

    String letterList[] = {"Types of industries", "Safety Sign's",
    "Tools & equipments", "Slogens", "Low", "Definitions", "First aid kit", "Near by fire stations"};

    int lettersIcon[] = {R.drawable.safetyicon, R.drawable.signs, R.drawable.tools,
    R.drawable.slogen, R.drawable.low, R.drawable.definitions,
    R.drawable.firstkit, R.drawable.firestations};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_navigation_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);

    GridAdapter adapter = new GridAdapter(NavigationMainActivity.this, lettersIcon, letterList);

    gridView.setAdapter(adapter);

    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id)
        {
            // Sending image id to FullScreenActivity
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TypesOfIndusturies.class);
        }
    });
```

Comment: please add your custom layout here.

Comment: This is possible duplicate question. You can check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/31356794/4379833